Cannot change solution for PowerPages project in the data tab
I want to import external data into my PowerPages project, but the current solution, which is set to Active solution is preventing me from importing the external data. Importing data worked just fine when the solution was set to Common Data Services Solution.
Here are the steps I tried to do to fix the issue:

click on the "Data" tab on the left hand side
click on the cog wheel next to the "Data" header
click on "Common Data Services Default Solution".

The last step throws a 400 error in the networking tab. The same error is thrown if I click on any of the other solutions, including the one that is currently selected (Active Solution).
error thrown when clicking on a solution in the Data tab
The server resonds with:
{
"error": {
"code": "0x80072013",
"message": "Cannot complete the creation of EnvironmentVariableValue because it violates a          database constraint. The violation happens on the key environmentvariabledefinitionid: 4e18ac4a-748c-ef11-ac20-000d3a65de79. Please delete the existing record or use update."
}
}
When I try to import an external table, I get an error:
"The given solution name is not valid (Active)."
this is what the networking tab says:
{
"error": {
"code": "",
"message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI   'https://org76c43412.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/msdyn_create_virtual_table_v2'."
}
}
I tried to do the following:

click on the "Data" tab on the left hand side
click on the cog wheel next to the "Data" header
click on "Common Data Services Default Solution".

I expected the solution type to change and not receive an error when trying to import an external table
{
"error": {
"code": "",
"message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://org76c43412.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/msdyn_create_virtual_table_v2'."
}
}
